# Erro 404 ao configurar URL personalizadas

Tags: wordpress

fiz a migração de um site wordpress / plesk (local para web) e funciona tudo bem menos um detalhe:

O site só funciona se as páginas tiverem o seguinte formato: http://brasilcacambas.com.br/?p=123 se eu configurar pra aparecer assim: http://brasilcacambas.com.br/post-exemplo/ recebo um erro 404.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que criar um arquivo web.config com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 1):

Italo, você tem que configurar novamente os links permanentes do wordpress e dai ele vai te gerar um arquivo ***.htaccess*** correto no servidor com o redirecionamento pros URLs amigáveis.

Ou você pode deletar o ***.htaccess*** antigo e ir nas configurações e em links permanentes e salvar novamente para que o arquivo novo seja gerado

Caso informe que não foi possivel criar o arquivo o wordpress irá exibir o código, você cria um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do seu servidor (geralmente `/var/www/html` ou `/public-html`) e cola o código lá :)

Comment: oi amigo, resolvi. postei a resposta ontem. abraço

Comment: Tranquilo vou marcar a resposta como +1